# Rails finding a value in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, loops, block

Is it possible to call the *include?* function on a whole table, like this?

```
<% @user.games.each do |g|
   @@latestround = g.rounds.order('created_at DESC').first
%>
    <% if @@latestround.submittedpictures.isFinalPicture.include?(true) %>
        <p>FinalPicture has been played!</p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem i'm getting is that It only works when I put a block on submittedpictures and then loop through each record of this table. However I want to look through the whole table in one go and see if the column 'isFinalPicture' includes a value with 'false'.

Any ideas?

The following snippet works but its not the way i want it (I would get more lines if the round happens to have more 'true' FinalPictures)

```
<% @@latestround.submittedpictures.each do |s| %>
    <% if s.isFinalPicture == true %>
         <p>Final Picture has been played!</p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post your model code so we can see what's going on in isFinalPicture?

Comment: Also note that your code does not really follow the ruby naming conventions.. Ruby usually seperates words with _ and has no upper case characters in it.. Yours looks more like JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a scope for it like

```
class SubmitedPricture << ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :final_pictures, where('isFinalPricture = ?', true)
end
```

then you could see if there is any with only one query

```
latestround.submittedpictures.final_pictures.any?
```

Also you should follow the conventions of Rails in naming your Models and everything else. Like submittedpictures should be submitted_pictures

Comment: oh my bad ill change the name right away. My teacher handed over the database setup and I didnt question the naming :) Also thanks for the solution i was looking for this exact thing :)

Comment: oh, it worked? I was not sure if it was possible to do the scope work this way